# How to update a table to remove special characters and return only the alphanumeric values -Teradata

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I need to remove special characters from Teradata columns and only return back the alphanumeric values. I have tried using **REGEXP_REPLACE(column,'[^0-9a-z]', '', 1,0,'i')** but it is not working and I need to remove these special character from and existing table so would need to run an update query.

what would be the correct syntax for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This regex should work, can you show an example?

Comment: sel REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'[^0-9a-z]', '', 1,0,'i') as col from tb1 and it is not filtering. but I'd need an update query and don't know how to reformat it or if there is another query that can achieve this instead of REGEXP_REPLACE. thanks.

Comment: What does *it is not filtering* mean? Can you provide some input data and (unexpected) output?